# Change index of crosstab in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have following data-frame df. I retrieved subset of df without NAN.

```
#df is:

    DT   RE   FE   SE   C_Step
0   D1   E1   F1   S1     poor
1   D2   E3   F2  NaN  UNKNOWN
2   D1   E3  NaN   S2  UNKNOWN
3   D1  NaN   F1   S1     poor
4   D2  NaN   F1   S2     poor
5   D2   E3  NaN   S1     fair
6   D1   E3   F1   S2     fair
7   D2   E2   F1   S1  UNKNOWN
8   D2   E2   F1   S1     fair
9   D2   E2  NaN  NaN     good
10  D2   E2   F1   S1  UNKNOWN
11  D1   E3   F2   S1  UNKNOWN
12  D2   E1   F2   S2  UNKNOWN
13  D2   E1   F1   S2     poor
14  D2   E3   F1   S1     fair
15  D1   E3   F1   S2  UNKNOWN



df_subset = df[~(df.iloc[:, 0:4].isnull().any(1))]
print(df_subset)

#df_subset is:

    DT  RE  FE  SE   C_Step
0   D1  E1  F1  S1     poor
6   D1  E3  F1  S2     fair
7   D2  E2  F1  S1  UNKNOWN
8   D2  E2  F1  S1     fair
10  D2  E2  F1  S1  UNKNOWN
11  D1  E3  F2  S1  UNKNOWN
12  D2  E1  F2  S2  UNKNOWN
13  D2  E1  F1  S2     poor
14  D2  E3  F1  S1     fair
15  D1  E3  F1  S2  UNKNOWN
```

After this I try to make cross-tab from both df and df_subset data-frames, 'C_Step' for index and 'RE' for column

Cross-tab from df:

```
c1 = pd.crosstab([df.C_Step],[df.RE],dropna=True)
print(c1)

RE       E1  E2  E3
C_Step             
UNKNOWN   1   2   4
fair      0   1   3
good      0   1   0
poor      2   0   0
```

Cross tab from df_subset:

```
c1 = pd.crosstab([df_subset.C_Step],[df_subset.RE],dropna=False)
print(c1)

RE       E1  E2  E3
C_Step             
UNKNOWN   1   2   2
fair      0   1   2
poor      2   0   0
```

**Question:** Index of both crosstab is different. How Can I have index of cross-tab generated from 'df_subset' same as 'df'? Category 'good' is missing in cross-tab of df_subset

T**he desired cross-tab of df_subset is:**

```
RE       E1  E2  E3
C_Step             
UNKNOWN   1   2   2
fair      0   1   2
good      0   0   0
poor      2   0   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
c2 = pd.crosstab([df_subset.C_Step], [df_subset.RE], dropna=False)
c2 = c2.reindex(c1.index, fill_value=0)

print(c2)
RE       E1  E2  E3
C_Step             
UNKNOWN   1   2   2
fair      0   1   2
good      0   0   0
poor      2   0   0
```